# Wordpress theme: Custom page template displays all the website's pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developping a wordpress theme. I'm making a custom theme for a specific page.

I created a "Home" page with the identifier "home". I created a page-home.php file, with this loop:

```
<?php get_header();
get_topmenu(); ?>

    <div class="catch"></div>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area page-home">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </article><!-- #post -->

                <?php comments_template(); ?>
             <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    PAGE HOME.PHP


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But doing this, when I call ?q=home, I've got ALL my pages displayed in the loop, and not just the "home" page... What is the cleanest way to get just the "Home" page ?

Comment: Why are you using The Loop if its just one page ?

Comment: I looked for a way to display the current page only, but all that I found was this loop or a many lines query that didn't seem clean...

Comment: Remove The Loop and use the post/page ID directly in the query. It should do the trick.